# How to match geom_ribbon fill to geom_line color (using ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, viridis

I am trying to create a line plot for two continuous variables (xy) with shading for the confidence interval, but with custom **and matched** colors for the line and the shading. GGplot correctly takes (discrete) colors from the viridis scale for the line, but I cannot get it to map the same colors (with lower alpha) to the geom_ribbon that I am using to plot the confidence interval.

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672736/custom-colours-for-geom-ribbon-fill-based-for-categorical-data), I've tried using scale_color_manual but I can't get that to work either (even when I recode `rej` to character 'yes'/'no', or to a factor with those levels).

I've also tried setting the `fill` and `color` aesthetics directly in the call to `ggplot`, i.e.,

```
my_plot <- ggplot(data = my_data, aes(fill = rej, color = rej))
```

Here's the minimal example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

my_data <- structure(list(time = c(-0.1, 1.8, 3.7, 5.6, 7.5, 9.4, 11.3, 13.2, 
15.1, 17, -0.1, 1.8, 3.7, 5.6, 7.5, 9.4, 11.3, 13.2, 15.1, 17), value = c(-0.02, 
-0.05, -0.03, 0.03, 0.11, 0.11, 0.06, 0.01, -0.04, -0.18, -0.03, -0.05, -0.01, 
0.06, 0.14, 0.15, 0.09, 0.01, -0.07, -0.19), lower = c(-0.05, -0.12, -0.1, 
-0.05, 0.03, 0.04, -0.02, -0.07, -0.13, -0.33, -0.06, -0.12, -0.1, -0.03, 0.05, 
0.06, 0, -0.08, -0.16, -0.36), upper = c(0.02, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.18, 0.19, 
0.14, 0.1, 0.04, -0.02, 0.01, 0.03, 0.07, 0.14, 0.22, 0.23, 0.18, 0.1, 0.03, 
-0.01), rej = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)), 
row.names = c(11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 
44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L), class = "data.frame")

my_plot <- ggplot(data = my_data) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = time, ymin = lower, ymax = upper, fill = rej), alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = value, color = rej), lwd = 3) + # line width increased for visibility
  scale_color_viridis_d(begin = 0, end = 1, option = 'viridis')
my_plot
```

Since the `color` argument for `geom_line` and the `fill` argument for `geom_ribbon` are set using the same variable, I am expecting the colors of lines and ribbons to match. What I get instead is a plot with lines and ribbons, but the colors of the ribbons do not match the colors of the lines (this can be confirmed by removing the `alpha = 0.3` setting from the `geom_ribbon` arguments in the code above):

[image: ribbon colors do not match line colors]

Is there any way to get ggplot to match the colors?

Comment: You need to set a scale for both the color and the fill. You can setup the fill the same as you've done for color

Comment: Or add `aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")` inside `scale_color_viridis_d()` if you want to use the same exact values for both.

Comment: Thanks a lot - both solutions seem to work. I'd be happy to accept an answer from either of you.